# Инструментарий для создания 3D игр

Tags: delphi, разработка-игр

Добрый день, *хэшкодчане*.

Не хочу устраивать холивар (но чувствую, что он появится, если вопрос не забракуют), но у меня такой вопрос:

*Начну издалека*
Сейчас работаю в %organization%, сопровождаю внедренную мной ИС, разработанную мной же на Delphi, и разбираюсь с 1С программированием. Но порой хочется какого-то разнообразия, чего-то новенького, интересненького.

*По делу*
Подскажите, пожалуйста, IDE и сопутствующие библиотеки для работы с 3D графикой, чтобы при углубленном изучении можно было крафтить простенькие (для начала) игрушки. Хотел бы в свободное время немножко *саморазвиться*. Может быть, кто-то этим серьезно занимается, или у кого-то хобби? Если еще и литературу/блоги/форумы подскажите, буду рад.

PS. Пытался найти библиотеки и компоненты для делфи, но это занятие не увенчалось успехом - всё какое-то обрубленное, недописанное, недоделанное, с кучей ошибок в коде...

PPS. Пытался поискать эту информацию в интернете, на тематических холиварах, но моя неграмотность в других IDE не позволила мне проникнуться этим вопросом.

PPPS. Не надо разжевывать все, я просто прошу дать мне точку опоры, а Землю я уж сам сдвину.

Comment: blender (http://www.blender.org). Там и игры можно писать (см. game engine), и скрипты на питоне. И прочие вещи с 3D.

Comment: Мозг самый лучший инструмент)

Answer (score 3):

[GlScene](http://glscene.sourceforge.net/wikka/HomePage)
from OpenGl

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите [обзор технологий](http://www.slideshare.net/vkozhaev/ss-12298009). Возможно, найдете что-нибудь интересное для себя.

А еще сюда можете зайти:

- [Программируем графику на Direct3D 11 в среде .NET](http://habrahabr.ru/post/142025/)
- [Программируем графику на Direct3D 11 в среде .NET (часть 1)](http://habrahabr.ru/post/142102/)
- [Induc по-прежнему угроза для Delphi](http://habrahabr.ru/post/136841/)

Answer (score 0):

[unity3d](https://unity3d.com/ru)

Не совсем для Delphi но сейчас это тренд. Если для WebGL то Babylon.js.